# Ask for user input, if yes do function, if no quit program

Tags: python, function, input

```
def main():
    plainText = input("Enter a one-word, lowercase message: ")
    distance = int(input("Enter the distance value: "))
    code = ""
    for ch in plainText:
        ordValue = ord(ch)
        cipherValue = ordValue + distance
        if cipherValue > ord('z'):
            cipherValue = ord('a') + distance - (ord('z') - ordValue + 1)
        code +=  chr(cipherValue)
    print(code)

    userDecrypt = input("Would you like to decrypt the text? ").lower

    # i want this yes answer to force the next few lines of code to run and if no then it quits the program
    if userDecrypt == 'yes' or userDecrypt == 'y':
        code = code
        plainText = ""
        for ch in code:
            ordValue = ord(ch)
            cipherValue = ordValue - distance
            if cipherValue < ord('a'):
                cipherValue = ord('z') - (distance - (ord('a') - ordValue + 1))
            plainText += chr(cipherValue)
    print(plainText)

        # this is where my problem lies. It won't allow this
        elif userDecrypt == 'no' or userDecrypt == 'n': 
            print("Have a good day")

main()
```

The `elif` statement is my problem. I want to be able to run the decrypt code if the user selects yes and if no then i want the program to quit. I can get it to decode if yes but when i add the else statement i get error messages: invalid syntax. I know i am over thinking this.

Comment: Indentation matters in Python.

Comment: You don't have any `else` statement.

Comment: sorry it was where the elif was i kept changing it to find the error. I also added just, "if userDecrypt == 'no' or userDecrypt == 'n'

Comment: I don't know if its that my indentation is wrong for the whole function or if its a problem with the wording.

Comment: if userDecrypt == 'no' or userDecrypt == 'n':
        print("Have a good day")                                                                              when i add this it runs without error but when the user selects no it still decodes the message

Answer (score 0):

I see several problems in the code as posted:

1. There's a `.lower` call missing parentheses (note that `'xyz'.lower` without parens will *always* evaluate as `True`)
2. `print(plainText)` needs to be indented
3. The `elif` branch needs to be outdented to line up with `if` branch it goes with
4. `code = code` doesn't do anything
5. The `plainText` variable shouldn't be reused; instead you should use a new variable such as `decodedText`

Comment: that did help me get the correct no answer but it changed the decryption and it doesn't give me the correct yes answer. I never expected python to be so hard....

Comment: I know this sounds weird but adding just the .lower instead of .lower() allowed the program to correctly decrypt the message. It was the only thing that allowed the y and z's in a name to correctly loop back around the alphabet.